# find the <td> column value of respective cell using any javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to find the column number of **td** containing X using jQuery or some other JavaScript library.

For example column number of **td** containing **A** is **1** and **B** is **3**.

Also we know that column number of **td** containing **X** is **1**. But  how can we get that pragmatically.

My case here is I need to merge data of all the rows with first row. So while moving through each **td** I need to know from which column does it belong so that I can merge it to the **td** of first row of that column.
Please help me if there is any other approach to solve my problem.

Comment: use `:contains()` selector

Comment: @guradio and take into consideration the `rowspan`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is basically storing your table data into an array, and intended if you ever want to expand or modify the structure of your table **rowspan**. *(This does not support colspan)*

```js
$(function() {
  var tableArr = [],
    totalRow = $('table tr').length,
    totalCol = 0;

  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var colLength = $(this).children('td').length;
    totalCol = colLength > totalCol ? colLength : totalCol;
  });

  for (var r = 0; r < totalRow; r++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < totalCol; c++) {
      row.push(null);
    }
    tableArr.push(row);
  }

  $('td').each(function() {
    var rowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent('tr').index();
    var colIndex = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).html();

    if (rowspan && rowspan > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rowspan; i++) {
        tableArr[i][colIndex] = text;
      }
    } else {
      var lastNull = tableArr[rowIndex].indexOf(null);
      tableArr[rowIndex][lastNull] = text;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your table information is stored within `tableArr`, which you use to query if you want to get desired `columnIndex` based on the content of your `td`.

**Usage**

```
// This returns an array containing [row, column];
function getPositionByText(str) {
  for (var r = 0; r < tableArr.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < tableArr[r].length; c++) {
      if (tableArr[r][c] === str) {
        return [r, c]
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

var position = getPositionByText('X');
var xRow = position[0];
var xCol = position[1];
```

---

Comment: this does not return the column number.

Comment: and the `rowspan` ?

Comment: My case here is I need to merge data of all the rows with first row. So while moving through each td I need to know from which column does it belong so that I can merge it to the td of first row of that column. Please help me if there is any other approach to solve my problem.

Comment: @wrufesh What is the expected result of your table?

Comment: Your solution gives the index excluding the **td** engulfed by rowspan.

Comment: like index of <td>B</td> should be 3.

Comment: @wrufesh Oh.. I think im almost getting it. So, will the `rowspan` ever invented in any other but the 1st row? .. And if `B` is `3`, then `A` should be `1`, right?

Comment: @choz exactly A should be 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qa5w5zt3/).

It gets the index and looks for `rowspan`s and calculates the visible index.

```
function getColumnNumber(text) {
    var $table = $("table").eq(0);
    $("td:contains(" + text + ")").css("color", "red");
    var $td = $("td:contains(" + text + ")"),
        $tr = $td.parent(),
        tdPosition = $td.index(),
        trPosition = $tr.index(),
        position = parseInt(tdPosition);
    for (i = 0; i < trPosition; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= tdPosition; j++) {
            var rowSpan = parseInt($table.find('tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(j).attr("rowspan"));
            if (typeof rowSpan !== "number") {
                rowSpan = 0;
            }
            if (rowSpan > trPosition) {
                position++;
                tdPosition++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(text + " pos: " + position);
    return position;
};
getColumnNumber('A');
getColumnNumber('B');
getColumnNumber('1');
getColumnNumber('Y');
```

Comment: What if we have some element instead of **A**? Will this script work?

Comment: Meaning you will search for something else? We can always redefine the searching function that retrieves the programatic index of the column within the row.

Comment: Yes like if I have a link inside <td>. I have to call function like getColumnNumber('<a>Foo</a>'). Or getColumnNumber($('.link')).

Comment: Well. I can add another param and you could specify the function that searches through the items.